# How to minimize the WPF application into the bottom right corner of desktop?

Tags: c#, wpf

Does anyone know how to minimize the wpf window into the bottom right corner by click on some button? I want this happen when i click on the X button.

Thanks.

Comment: [**Here is how**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269723/) you do it with WinForms. Perhaps this will help get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NotifyIcon control is used to add an item to the systray.  I dont think it exists in WPF but you should be able to use the winforms one in your app.

There are some WPF samples around on implementing from scratch.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/aacbc77c-4ef6-456f-80b7-1f157c2909f7